# Preload image in browser for display after server disconnection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS along with HTML5 Server-Side Events (SSE) to continuously update the display of some data in a web page. As part of this, I have an icon to display the state of the connection to the server.

I am using an `ng-switch` to control whether to display my "connected" or "disconnected" icon. This switches on a $scope variable that I modify from the SSE `onopen` and `onerror` callbacks. This is working so long as the server is still able to serve static HTTP requests.

However, if the server shuts down *completely* then I get a missing-image placeholder in the browser instead of my desired image. This happens because it is the first time the browser has needed the image, but the server is no longer up and cannot serve the static file.

So I'm looking for ways to preload the image in order that the browser doesn't need to request it after the SSE `onerror` callback. I've tried the following and they didn't work, i.e. the browser still requests the image and gets an error:

- I created an always-displayed `<img>` in the HTML with the same `src` URL, but set it to 1x1 pixel to make it invisible.
- I tried loading the image directly from my controller initialisation using `$http.get()`.
- I even tried the following in my HTML `<head>` section:

```html
<script>
    var disconnectedImg = new Image(16, 16);
    disconnectedImg.src = 'static/img/disconnected.png';
</script>
```

I'd be very grateful for any ideas at this point! Do I need to set any particular cache-control headers from the server when I serve the image?

Comment: Why doesn't it work to load the image once (on initial load), hide it by default with `display: none;` and show it when `onerror` is triggered?

Comment: you can use an html manifest to preload everything as soon as the app hits the browser...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, the manifest idea looks like a good solution, and something I wasn't aware of. I'll give it a try. If you promote your comment to an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing what bbuecherl suggested and just have the image always in the DOM with `display: none` until needed.

You could also trying prefetching the image so it will be in the cache:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-prefetch